# Загрузка страницы aliexpress

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Питаюсь парсить [карточку товаров aliexpress](https://m.ru.aliexpress.com/s/item/32832914406.html?spm=a2g0n.home.home-qp.1.79d904c6iJV6Za&scm=1007.14557.83665.0) сначала думал буду парсить через Simple HTML DOM но перейдя на мобильную версию, вижу что все ответы получают через ajax:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

но выдернуть через `curl` у меня что то не получается.

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}
print_r(file_get_contents_curl('https://m.ru.aliexpress.com/ajaxapi/product/ajaxDetail.do?productId=32832914406'));
```

Тут я думаю либо дело в куках либо в заголовках. Даже если так то откуда их брать и как правильно их отправить?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На будущее: можно в хроме нажать правой кнопкой на запрос => `Copy` => `Copy as cUlr` и в буфере появится curl команда целиком. Осталось просто вставить в консоль и смотреть результат.

Методом постепенного вычищения лишних заголовков пришел в минимальному виду запроса. На самом деле достаточно добавить заголовок:

```
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => [
    'referer: https://m.ru.aliexpress.com/',
]
```

Тогда алиекспресс отдаст Вам все, что нужно.

Вот команда для проверки:

```
curl 'https://m.ru.aliexpress.com/ajaxapi/product/ajaxDetail.do?productId=32679283205' -H 'referer: https://m.ru.aliexpress.com/' --compressed
```

Comment: А как вы пришли к тому что именно надо добавить `referer` вы проверили где-то или куда-то все загаловки?

Comment: Вставил в командную строку и получил что то не понятное: https://pp.userapi.com/c639919/v639919398/56b93/3bMqoE_WeeM.jpg

Comment: @newProgrammer, потому что curl нужно установить. А к referer я, пришел убирая поочередно заголовки, которые были при запросе внутри сайта.

Comment: Понял спасибо.,

Answer (score 3):

Не забываем про https.
Как уже сказали выше полный код будет выглядеть так, **работает**:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'https://m.ru.aliexpress.com/');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

echo file_get_contents_curl('https://m.ru.aliexpress.com/ajaxapi/product/ajaxDetail.do?productId=32832914406');
```

> Вставил в командную строку и получил что то не понятное

Не туда вставляете.

Comment: За код спасибо, но хотелось бы еще узнать на будущее, как решить подобные задачи?

Comment: @newProgrammer все там же, во вкладке Network. Если запрос не проходит, значит проблема в заголовках. Берем все заголовки и убираем по одному. На каком поменяется запрос, тот и важен

Comment: Я думал что в браузер можно сразу узнать какой именно важен. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Как вы правильно заметили, дело в куках и заголовках и возможно в передаче данных через POST-запрос:

```
    $options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER=>array('Content-Type: ...', 'Cookie: ...'),
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => http_build_query($post_fields),
        CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 20,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 20,
        CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'
    );

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
    $data = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
```

В CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER передаете все заголовки (в т.ч. cookies, т.к. последние с точки зрения сервера как раз и являются заголовками), в CURLOPT_USERAGENT передаете заголовок User Agent'а (желательно тот, под которым и были получены cookies).